# contenteditable="true": creating a syntax highlighted input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, plugins

I'm currently fiddling around with contenteditable="true" to create a syntax highlighted input box. I'm writing a jquery plugin that converts a `<input>` tag to a `<div contenteditable="true">` container. In detail, it hides the `<input>` and inserts the `<div>` container after it.

In my fiddle, the highlight function is just a simple replace function to highlight all 'AND's in the container. Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Rhz8/2/

If the content of the container is changed, the plugin has to

- sync the content with the content of the input
- update the syntax highlighting

In my example, I'm just listening to the keyup event. Now, there's a problem when I want to update the syntax highlighting of the container. When the input is changed via `.html()` or the container's `innerHTML` property, the cursor state resets. Is there a way to prevent this, or can I save/restore the cursor position ?

Comment: Look at this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381205/get-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a perfect API for saving and restoring the cursor position: 
http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

It's the rangy API.
All you have to do is

```
var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
```

to save the cursor position and then

```
rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel);
```

to restore the cursor position. You can read more about this here: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule