# cursor in transparent textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntax-highlighting

I wrote a small jQuery-plugin to highlight different parts in a textarea.

I added a `<pre>` behind the textarea which displays the code highlighted, the textarea is transparent:

HTML:

```
<textarea class="edit" rows="10"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
pre {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;

    outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.edit {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50%;

    color: #000;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;

    resize: vertical;
}

pre, .edit {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    tab-size: 4;
    -o-tab-size: 4;
    -moz-tab-size: 4;

    line-height: 17px;
    font-family: monospace; 
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').after('<pre></pre>');

    var $code = $('pre');
    var position = $('.edit').position();

    $code.css('left', position.left + 'px');
    $code.css('top', position.top + 'px');
    $code.css('width', $('.edit').innerWidth() + 'px');
    $code.css('height', $('.edit').innerHeight() + 'px');

    $('.edit').on('input', function() {
         $('pre').html($(this).val());   
    });
});
```

Here is a preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Recode/HaPAe/

If I change the `color` of the text in the textarea to `transparent`, the cursor also disappears, because in Firefox (and some other browsers) it has always the same color as the text.

I found this snippet:

```
.edit { cursor: url(cursor.cur), default; }
```

But this changes only the mouse-cursor and not the one that says where I am in my text.

Is there a way to have a visible cursor although the text is transparent?

Comment: is content editable in pre itself will not do the job for you, why you need a textarea and make it transparent and all

Comment: Because textarea already contains all the methods like pasting, ... and pre will contain other html later.

Comment: content editable allows you to paste and all

Comment: Thanks, you should have written an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having happens because the colour of the insertion cursor is the same as the color of the text.

### WebKit-only Solution

In WebKit browsers you can get around this by using the `-webkit-text-fill-color` property and setting that to `transparent` whilst still using a solid `color`:

```
.edit {
    color:#000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/HaPAe/1/) where I've set the color to `#f00` - you can see the red insertion cursor, but you can't see the textarea text.

Unfortunately this will not work on Firefox or other non-WebKit browsers.

### Non-WebKit Solution

Depending on what level of browser support you're going for, you can always drop the `textarea` completely and set the `pre` to `contenteditable`. jQuery's `on('input'...)` event handler will still trigger when applied to `pre` elements.

```
<pre contenteditable></pre>
```

```
$('pre').on('input', function() { ... });
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/HaPAe/3/).

Do note though that with this you may need to strip formatting.

Comment: I should use more HTML5. Thanks.

Comment: But how can I insert tabs then? I used selectionStart and selectionEnd, but they are not available in `<pre>` elements.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381205/get-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div